vs code Go To Definition for alias path css import in Astro project does not takes to original file but to client.d.ts file
I have Astro based project where using path alias for css file.

 {
   "paths": {
      "@/assets/*": [
        "src/assets/*"
      ]
   }
}

and here is importing css file in .astro file
import "@/assets/styles/theme.css";

now when hover the import statment and select Go to Definition ;

it takes to node_modules/astro/client.d.ts file
declare module '*.css' {
    const css: string;
    export default css;
}

where css declaration added while it should takes to the original file
How to fix this?

vs code v 1.94
astro v 4.16.1

